# Running a Java sentinel-controlled do-while loop in public method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while, sentinel

I have a method, `public static int payMethod`, with parameter `input` for `Scanner` to get, well, input. Obviously, I could remove the method entirely and put everything in the `main` method, but I'm trying to learn about using different types of methods so that isn't really an option.

My goal is for the user to input 1, 2, or 3. If they input something else, then the program asks again, until the user inputs 1, 2, or 3.

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //User input on selection
        System.out.println("Choose 1, 2, or 3.");
        double choice;

        //Repeat until payment selection is valid choice
        choice = choiceMethod(input);

        input.close(); //Close Scanner
    }

    public static int choiceMethod (Scanner input) {
        do {
            System.out.print("Which choice would you like? ");
            if (input.nextDouble() < 1 || input.nextDouble() > 3 || input.nextDouble() != (int)input.nextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("This is not a valid option. Please choose either option 1, 2, or 3.");
            }
        } while (input.nextDouble() < 1 || input.nextDouble() > 3 || input.nextDouble() != (int)input.nextDouble());
        return (int)input.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Here is my wonky input/output.

```
Choose 1, 2, or 3.
Which choice would you like? 1

2
3
4
This is not a valid option. Please choose either option 1, 2, or 3.
5





1
1
2
Which choice would you like? 
2
3
4
5
This is not a valid option. Please choose either option 1, 2, or 3.
```

I've tried changing parameters to no avail, so I'm sure the problem is something within the method. Help is appreciated, TIA.

Comment: You call `input.nextDouble()` as many times as it takes to short-circuit the logic expression. Get the input *then* process it via an intermediate variable otherwise you need to consume an arbitrary (but bounded) number of doubles before the method can continue.

Comment: @DaveNewton Tried it out and it works, makes sense, thanks